# Receive commands from a specific channel

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

How can I make the bot receive commands from specific channels, and if there is no channel, it is received from all channels and it is connected to mongoDB?

I can do the receiving command from a specific channel using channel ID, but I want via the command:

`!setChannel #ID_CHANNEL OR mention`

I tried these codes

```js
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please Mention Channel');
if(!channel) return message.channel.send('Please Mention Vaild Channel');

/*-----------------------------in mongedb add Guild id + channel id------------------------------

in quick.db it is like this -->

db.set("commands_channel_"+ message.guild.id + channel.id, true)*/

message.channel.send(`Commands Channel: ${channel}`);
```

```js
let CommandsChannel = db.get("commands_channel_"+ message.guild.id + channel.id)
if(!CommandsChannel) return
//-------------------------------//
if(CommandsChannel = true) {

// else command code //
}
```

Comment: What went wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

wrong with the code

```js
(node:4456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `commands_channel_708596988995829762709436321805893753` is an invalid option.
    at Mongoose.set (/rbd/pnpm-volume/34e95e32-ea3c-4e44-8fb4-6f803dcbc088/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/5.10.15/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:179:48)
at Object.run (/app/commands/admin/setchannel.js:19:10)
at module.exports (/app/events/message.js:152:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
(node:4456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```